# Advisable ways to shape my data as input for a RNN

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a dataframe X, where each row is a data point in time and each column is a feature. The label/target variable Y is univariate. One of the columns of X is the lagged values of Y.

The RNN input is of the shape (batch_size, n_timesteps, n_feature).

From what I've been reading on this site, batch_size should be as big as possible without running out of memory. My main doubt is about n_timesteps. and n_features.

I think n_feature is the number of columns in the X dataframe.

What about the n_timesteps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following `dataframe` with the features temperature, pressure, and humidity:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'temperature': np.random.random((1, 20)).ravel(),
    'pressure': np.random.random((1, 20)).ravel(),
    'humidity': np.random.random((1, 20)).ravel(),
})

print(X.to_markdown())
```

```
|    |   temperature |   pressure |   humidity |
|---:|--------------:|-----------:|-----------:|
|  0 |     0.205905  |  0.0824903 | 0.629692   |
|  1 |     0.280732  |  0.107473  | 0.588672   |
|  2 |     0.0113955 |  0.746447  | 0.156373   |
|  3 |     0.205553  |  0.957509  | 0.184099   |
|  4 |     0.741808  |  0.689842  | 0.0891679  |
|  5 |     0.408923  |  0.0685223 | 0.317061   |
|  6 |     0.678908  |  0.064342  | 0.219736   |
|  7 |     0.600087  |  0.369806  | 0.632653   |
|  8 |     0.944992  |  0.552085  | 0.31689    |
|  9 |     0.183584  |  0.102664  | 0.545828   |
| 10 |     0.391229  |  0.839631  | 0.00644447 |
| 11 |     0.317618  |  0.288042  | 0.796232   |
| 12 |     0.789993  |  0.938448  | 0.568106   |
| 13 |     0.0615843 |  0.704498  | 0.0554465  |
| 14 |     0.172264  |  0.615129  | 0.633329   |
| 15 |     0.162544  |  0.439882  | 0.0185174  |
| 16 |     0.48592   |  0.280436  | 0.550733   |
| 17 |     0.0370098 |  0.790943  | 0.592646   |
| 18 |     0.371475  |  0.976977  | 0.460522   |
| 19 |     0.493215  |  0.381539  | 0.995716   |
```

Now, if you want to use this kind of data for time series prediction with a `RNN` model, you usually consider one row in the data frame as one timestep. Converting the `dataframe` into an array might also help you understand what the timesteps are:

```
print(np.expand_dims(X.to_numpy(), axis=1).shape)
# (20, 1, 3)
```

First, I obtain an array of the shape`(20, 3)` or in other words, 20 samples and each sample has three features. I then explicitly add a time dimension to the array, resulting in the shape`(20, 1, 3)`, meaning that the data set consists of 20 samples and each sample has one time step and for each time step you have 3 features. Now, you can use this data directly as input for a `RNN`.

Comment: It does! Many thanks ;)

Comment: Just one more question. If I had on each row, lags of each feature. Then, if I wanted to reshape into (batches, timestep, features) format, would it be important to get the order of the timesteps chronologically correct? i.e. imagine I have 2 lags on each row. Does it matter if at level 0 of the timestep  we have the oldest or the most recent value?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with lags? :)

Comment: Sure. ;) On each row we have the features for that time. Imagine now, we create new columns, with shifted (lagged) values (with pandas shift method).  If I do a shift of 1, then I'll have lagged values of the immediate past on each row. It could be something like X["past_temp"]=X["temp"].shift(1), and then we drop the nan.

Comment: Ah ok, yeah I would make sure the order is correct.

Comment: And how would that order look like? =D How should I order them?

Comment: Here it is. ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71184387/does-it-matter-the-ordering-of-rows-at-the-level-of-timesteps-for-a-rnn-input

Comment: This is confusing to me.  I am new to learning here, but was under the impression that a dataframe like the one above must be prepped for RNN in this way: [new_dimension, timesteps, features];  The new_dimension is the amount of batches of [timesteps, features].  So, above you should have shape: [1,20,3];  As you have 1 batch of 20 "timesteps" containing 3 "features".  Or could do 2 batches like so: [2,10,3];  batches, and timesteps being hyperparameters,  Is this incorrect?