# Does the ordering of 'rows' at the level of timesteps matter, for a RNN input in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

An RNN, in keras, accepts an input with the following shape

```
array([[['Xa0', 'Ya0'],
    ['Xa1', 'Ya1'],
    ['Xa2', 'Ya2']],

   [['Xb0', 'Yb0'],
    ['Xb1', 'Yb1'],
    ['Xb2', 'Yb2']],

   [['Xc0', 'Yc0'],
    ['Xc1', 'Yc1'],
    ['Xc2', 'Yc2']]], dtype='<U3')
```

The numbers are associated with the time steps (3 in our case), and X,Y are features. We have 3 batches (a,b,c).

Which order should I use:

1. 0 -> 2 from past to present?
2. 0 -> 2 from present to past?

and why?

Comment: Voting to close without any comments, it's not very helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to infer from the data?

### Do you want to classify it? Get a "true/false" result? Make a regression?

Any order is ok. Use the one that gives your network the best result. There is even the possibility of using `Bidirectional` layers, that will read the data both from past to present and from present to past.

### Do you want to predict next steps?

Use the order that leads to the steps you want to predict.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Btw, how many time_steps should one use? is there a criteria for choosing that number?

Comment: Test it. Usually, LSTM layers can take a very long number of steps. Of course, if you want to classify a sequence, you need the entire sequence.